# Adding gravity to networkx.spring_layout

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I'd like to add the notion of "gravity" to `networkx.spring_layout`. The reason is I have a DAG I'd like to layout and graphviz is having a lot of trouble with it. Initial experiments with `spring_layout` seem positive, but I'd like to ensure a more or less stable layout via applying a constant force to all nodes (decreasing each iteration with temperature of course). This should effectively "blow" all of the nodes in one direction or another, with the root being anchored in one place.

But, before starting that, I was wondering if this was a sound way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Graphviz has several programs for graph layouting, each is better for some types of graph. The standart program is used in networkx is `neato`. But there is one program that is far better for directed graphs, especially DAGs - `dot`. Just look at `neato` output:

`nx.draw(G, pos=nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G))`

[image]

and for `dot` output:

`nx.draw(G, pos=nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'))`

[image]

I strongly recommend you to use `graphviz_layout` with `prog='dot'`. But if you want to use the standart `spring_layout`, you should use `k` parameter. Spring layout [has no gravity parameter](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout), but `k` is the kind of it:

> `k (float (default=None)) – Optimal distance between nodes. If None the distance is set to 1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes. Increase this value to move nodes farther apart.`

You can also try to change `scale`:

> `scale (number (default: 1)) – Scale factor for positions. Not used unless fixed is None.`

and `seed` for deterministic graphs:

> `seed (int, RandomState instance or None optional (default=None)) – Set the random state for deterministic node layouts. If int, seed is the seed used by the random number generator, if numpy.random.RandomState instance, seed is the random number generator, if None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by numpy.random.`

Comment: this is a nice answer though I've tried these methods already. The reason I'm looking at extending spring_layout is that existing methods aren't sufficient. (and, i've tried tweaking a number of parameters on those existing methods).